# Need to sort data in snowflake and to pass to key-value pair dynamically from another table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create JSON file from table data in snowflake. I am doing object construct but it is not coming in order. (value is taken from table_test)

For example:

```
select OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL ('B', Beta,'A', Alpha)) AS value
from  table_test;
```

```
Sample Result: {
  "A": "Alpha",
  "B": "Beta"
}
```

But expected result should be in same like in select statement

```
{
  "B": "Beta",
  "A": "Alpha"
}
```

And my second query, this key value pair should be passed dynamically. I will maintain key value pair in another table. it has to be passed as parameter for object. suppose if I want to add another key pair such as C: Cassandra, I don't want to modify SQL I will add this new pair in another config table. So how to pass this dynamically

I am trying by creating stored proc to pass the key-value pair dynamically. but I am unable to pass multiple values

Comment: Hi - please limit yourself to one question/issue. Why do you care what the order is of key:value pairs in a JSON object?

Comment: @NickW, it is required to have in the given format

Comment: It's not possible. For a start JSON is, by definition, an un-ordered list of key:value pairs - so if you have anything that requires an order then it is not JSON compliant. Also, the documentation for OBJECT_CONSTRUCT_KEEP_NULL states "The constructed object does not necessarily preserve the original order of the key-value pairs"

Comment: As @NickW points out, the set of name-value pairs in JSON is by definition unordered. If you want an ordered set, you can use an array like this: `[{"B": "Beta"}, {"A": "Alpha"}]`

Comment: Thank you for helping in object construct. Please help me with second query that I want to pass key value pair dynamically that I will be stored in another table from there I read key value pair. Value represent field name of another table. So I want to pick data from there

Comment: If you have another question then please raise it in a separate post. Include table definitions, sample data, the result you want to achieve and what you’ve managed to write so far